# Typo3 backend module form error

Tags: typo3, form-submit, backend, builder

**I have no idea why, but the error just disappear without any changes. Now it works. I have not change anything. (I deleted cache many times so it cannot be because of the cache)**

*Problem*

I created an extension using extension builder (if anyone knows any good documentation please give me link because official documentation does not have any examples).
I have a form and when I submit the form I have the error

TYPO3 v4.7

> The action "formSave" (controller "Promoters") is not allowed by this plugin. Please check Tx_Extbase_Utility_Extension::configurePlugin() in your ext_localconf.php.

I created ext_localconf.php according to typo's wiki.

Form code

```
<f:form action="formSave" name="" object="">
  <f:form.textfield id="emailResendInterval" name="emailResendInterval" value="" />
  <f:form.textarea cols="30" rows="5" id="emails" name="emails" value="" />
  <f:form.submit name="submit" value="Save" />
</f:form>
```

ext_localconf.php

```
<?php
if (!defined ('TYPO3_MODE')) die ('Access denied.');
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF'][$_EXTKEY] = unserialize($_EXTCONF);
if ($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF'][$_EXTKEY]['registerSinglePlugin']) {
    // fully fletged blog
    Tx_Extbase_Utility_Extension::configurePlugin(
        $_EXTKEY,                                                                   // The extension name (in UpperCamelCase) or the extension key (in lower_underscore)
        'Promoters',                                                                        // A unique name of the plugin in UpperCamelCase
        array (                                                                     // An array holding the controller-action-combinations that are accessible
            'Promoters' => 'configuration,formSave',        // The first controller and its first action will be the default
        ),
        array(                                                                      // An array of non-cachable controller-action-combinations (they must already be enabled)
        )
    );
} else {
    Tx_Extbase_Utility_Extension::configurePlugin(
        $_EXTKEY,                                                                   // The extension name (in UpperCamelCase) or the extension key (in lower_underscore)
        'Promoters',                                                                        // A unique name of the plugin in UpperCamelCase
        array (                                                                     // An array holding the controller-action-combinations that are accessible
            'Promoters' => 'configuration,formSave',        // The first controller and its first action will be the default
        ),
        array(                                                                      // An array of non-cachable controller-action-combinations (they must already be enabled)
        )
    );
```

PromotersControler

```
class Tx_Promoters_Controller_PromotersController extends Tx_Extbase_MVC_Controller_ActionController {

    /**
     * action configuration
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function configurationAction() {

    }

    /**
     * action formSave
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function formSaveAction() {

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please also post your action? Are you using a flexform? If you might have to add your action to it.

Comment: I added the Controler if you meant that. I am not sure if I am using flexform so I suppose that I am not. I just made the extension with extension builder and then I tried to make the form works.

Answer (score 1):

Seems fine actually, I'm not sure about the if statemant in the localconf though. Please try this:

```
    <?php
        if (!defined ('TYPO3_MODE')) die ('Access denied.');

            // fully fletged blog
            Tx_Extbase_Utility_Extension::configurePlugin(
                $_EXTKEY,                      
                'Promoters',     
                array (
                    'Promoters' => 'configuration,formSave', 
                ),
                array(                        
                )
            );
    ?>
```

Comment: I found that "if" in some example extension.

Comment: Did you try it without?

Comment: I did. It is the same.

Comment: Is there a folder within your extension Configuration->FlexForms?

Comment: No there is not. But as I wrote in the question, it started to work without any change...

Comment: Puh, I start lacking ideas. You could try to add the controller attribute to the form: controller="Promoters". Is there more than one plugin instance on the site?